# how do you call a class in another class or ps1 file in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a code sample below. I dot reference the other powershell file. I create the new object in this file. End results is expected to return table from the results from this

```
Class start {
    [End]::new()
    [Object]$endResults = $End.GetData()
}
. .\End.ps1
[start]::new()
```

Comment: What is actually happening?

Comment: I need to create two classes. Then I need to set the result of one method in one class to the parameter of another class.

Comment: What did you try? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: If I try to run your code, I get a lot of errors. That is not valid class syntax, there is no constructor method to be called when you run `[start]::new()`, you aren't storing the result of `[end]::new()` anywhere, you haven't defined `$End`, you aren't returning `$endResults` to anything (which you can't, because it's not valid syntax). It looks like you have written a function and changed the `function` keyword to `Class` but they are not very similar; your code needs to be a lot different to use classes (and would be simpler with plain functions and using import-module instead of dotsource)